# Shifted spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, 3d, spherical-coordinates

I need to solve this integral:
$\int _V\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}dx\:dy\:dz$
where V is described with $x^2+y^2+z^2\le x$.

So, I know I could use shifted spherical coordinates but then the integral is hard to solve because of the function. 
But if I use normal spherical coordinates ( where the origin is in (0,0,0) ) it would be much easier to solve, but it's harder to find the boundaries for radius R. Does it depend both on θ and ϕ, or just on one of them?

(I'm using standard notation for angles, see here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system).

Could anyone be kind to help me find boundaries for R?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use spherical conversions, you get the equation

$$0 \leq \rho^2 \leq \rho \sin(\phi) \cos(\theta) \implies 0 \leq \rho \leq \sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)$$

So long as you are careful about how you do your bounds for $\phi$ and $\theta$ wouldn't that solve your problem?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I guess I was(am) tired so I didn't see that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Changing into spherical coordinates
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}x&=r\,\sin \theta \,\cos \varphi \\y&=r\,\sin \theta \,\sin \varphi \\z&=r\,\cos \theta \end{aligned}\right. \quad r\ge 0, \quad 0\le \theta \le \pi, \quad 0\le \varphi \le 2\pi
$$
the domain of integration becomes
$$
\tilde{V}=\{(r,\theta,\varphi)|\quad 0\le r\le \sin\theta\cos\varphi,\quad 0\le \theta \le \pi, \quad 0\le \varphi \le 2\pi\}.
$$
Since
\begin{eqnarray}
\dfrac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(r,\theta,\varphi)}&=&\left|\begin{array}{ccc}\sin\theta\cos\varphi&r\cos\theta\cos\varphi&-r\sin\theta\sin\varphi\\
\sin\theta\sin\varphi&r\cos\theta\sin\varphi&r\sin\theta\cos\varphi\\
\cos\theta&-r\sin\theta&0\end{array}\right|\\
&=&\cos\theta\left|\begin{array}{cc}r\cos\theta\cos\varphi&-r\sin\theta\sin\varphi\\
r\cos\theta\sin\varphi&r\sin\theta\cos\varphi\end{array}\right|+r\sin\theta\left|\begin{array}{cc}\sin\theta\cos\varphi&-r\sin\theta\sin\varphi\\
\sin\theta\sin\varphi&r\sin\theta\cos\varphi\end{array}\right|\\
&=&r^2\cos^2\theta\sin\theta+r^2\sin^3\theta=r^2\sin\theta
\end{eqnarray}
we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_V\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\,dx\,dy\,dz&=&\int_{\tilde{V}}r(r^2\sin\theta)\,dr\,d\theta\,d\varphi=\int_0^{2\pi}\,d\varphi\int_0^{\pi}\,d\theta\int_0^{\sin\theta\cos\varphi}r^3\sin\theta\,dr\\
&=&\dfrac14\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^4\varphi\,d\varphi\int_0^{\pi}\sin^5\theta\,d\theta=\dfrac12A_4B_5
\end{eqnarray}
[with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals)
\begin{eqnarray}
A_4&=&\int_0^\pi\cos^4\varphi\,d\varphi=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin^4t\,dt=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^4\,dt=2W_4=\dfrac{3\pi}{8}\\
B_5&=&\int_0^\pi\sin^5\theta\,d\theta=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos^5t\,dt=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^5t\,dt=2W_5=\dfrac{16}{15}
\end{eqnarray}
Hence
$$
\int_V\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\,dx\,dy\,dz=\dfrac12A_4B_5=\dfrac12\cdot\dfrac{3\pi}{8}\cdot\dfrac{16}{15}=\dfrac\pi5.
$$